# How to split strings by the commas and insert into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I have a function with a for loop that is returning a bunch of strings for example:

58, pluto
172, uno
5, peaches

How can I take the first part of the string (the number) in one column in a pandas dataframe and the second part (the fruit) in the second column. The columns should be named "amount" and "fruit".

Here is the code so far:

```
regex = r"(\d+)( ML/year )(in the |the )([\w \/\(\)]+)"
for line in finalText.splitlines():
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, line)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        print (match.group(1) +","+ match.group(4))
```

I am using re to filter out the data I need from a large block of text but for now it is just printing to the console and I need it to go into a dataframe.

Essentially, the last print statement in that code needs to be changed so instead of printing I am inserting into a dataframe.

Example of final text is:

(a)58 ML/Y in the pear region
(b)
64 ML/Y in the apple region

It is plain text

Comment: Append the dataframe using the append function. In your example, you want 58 and peaches? All others dropped?

Comment: Essentially I want match.group(1) in one column and match.group(4) in another column.

Comment: To split a string by comma, you can use `s.split(',')` where `s` is the name of the string

Comment: can u not give df[matchNum] = [match.group(1), match.group(4)]

Comment: first you need to define the dataframe by creating an empty one.

Comment: This returns an error with the pandas library unfortunately

Comment: did you import pandas? See my response in the answer section.

Comment: There may be an easier way to solve this instead of using loops. Can you share a few rows of  `finalText` It looks like the data is a csv file

Comment: I updated the question however finalText is just text not a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to work on figuring out a simpler solution for you. Use the \W regex to remove ()\ from your string.

If the pattern of your string is always going to be

```
(x)## ML/Y in the fruit region (y) ## ML/Y in the fruit region
```

then use this code. It will strip out the ( ) \ from the list and give you a simpler list. Use 3rd, 8th, 13th, and 18th position from the list to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

finalText = '(a)58 ML/Y in the pear region (b) 64 ML/Y in the apple region'

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['amount','fruit'])

for line in finalText.splitlines():
    matches = re.split(r'\W',line)
    df.loc[len(df)] = [matches[2],matches[7]]
    df.loc[len(df)] = [matches[12],matches[17]]

print(df)
```

The output for this resulted in:

```
  amount  fruit
0     58   pear
1     64  apple
```

An alternate way to do this will be to use findall.

```
for line in finalText.splitlines():
    print (line)
    m = re.findall(r'\w+',line)
    print (m)
    matches = re.findall(r'\w+',line)
    df.loc[len(df)] = [matches[1],matches[6]]
    df.loc[len(df)] = [matches[9],matches[14]]

print(df)
```

Same results as above

```
  amount  fruit
0     58   pear
1     64  apple
```

**old code**

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['amount','fruit'])

regex = r"(\d+)( ML/year )(in the |the )([\w \/\(\)]+)"
for line in finalText.splitlines():
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, line)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        df[matchNum] = [match.group(1) , match.group(4)]
```

Comment: The code runs with no errors but when I do df.head() it returns nothing

Comment: Nevermind when I print the df it does have the FIRST set of data however it is put in a third column together just on seperate rows

Comment: Did you get it working or do you need further help on this? If the issue is resolved, you can read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: Hi I still need further help. Your solution only seems to be partially working as it is not being formatted in the dataframe correctly and only the first line is being added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
s = "58, pluto 172, uno 5, peaches"
temp = s.split() # ['58,', 'pluto', '172,', 'uno', '5,', 'peaches']
amount = temp[::2] #['58,', '172,', '5,']
fruit = temp[1::2] # ['pluto', 'uno', 'peaches']
df['amount'] = amount
df['fruit'] = fruit
```

You can continue dropping the comma and change type from string to int

Comment: Hi I am not sure if this solution will work and I do not have a string like 's' as you have shown. Instead I need to put the specific match.group() items into the dataframe (match.group(1) and match.group(4))